# command not found

Tags: remote, scp

I have compile my code in my local computer terminal and after that I run `scp` command to transfer the result of the compiling to the `bin` of the remote computer.
When I tried to run my code from the remote computer, there was a message that command is not found as follow:

```
-bash-4.1$ fiscof2 <i16d06llyfi.dat >run26072016.log 

-bash: fiscof2: コマンドが見つかりません
```

This Japanese statement means, command not found.

Answer (score 1):

1. The directory in which you placed the file must be in your `$PATH`.  (Which `bin` ?  `/usr/bin` ?  `/home/$USER/bin` ?)
   In the directory containing your file, execute `./fiscof2` instead of `fiscof2` to avoid depending on your `$PATH`.
2. The file must have execute permissions.
   In the directory containing your file, execute `ls -l fiscof2`.  You should see a line beginning something like `-rwxr-xr-x`.  If the 'x' characters are not present, the execute permission is not set.  Change this with `chmod +x fiscof2`.
3. The file must be in executable format for the target system.  (i.e., if you compiled on and for AMD64, it will not run on a 32-bit system, or if you compile on Windows, it will not run on a linux system.)

Comment: I am sorry, I am still beginner in linux so most of your speech I couldn't understand it. could you explain in more details. 
what I have understand from your speech that I  can't compile the code in my computer and transfer the result of compiling to remote computer and run it after that. Isn't it?